# TortoiseSVN folder-rename invariably fails

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Whenever I rename a folder using ToroiseSVN, and then do a commit on the parent folder, it gets ugly. I typically get some weird tree conflict, and errors about SVN .tmp files/folders not existing, and other obscure messages I've never seen before. It's pretty stressful considering the folder is being deleted and supposedly recreated, what if it just gets deleted or mangled in some horrible way?

Is it better to do the rename directly on the repo, rather than on the working copy?
Are these problems normal?

Comment: I agree completely.  I've been pulling my hair out over the last few days dealing with this nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these problems normal?

No. As long as you go through the **TortoiseSVN menu** to move/rename things, everything should work fine.

Examples of bad things you should never do:

- moving/copying/renaming/deleting a versioned folder in your working copy with explorer
- changing the content of .svn folders
- deleting .svn folders (use the export feature instead)

I was involved in the training of users who migrated from VSS to SVN+TortoiseSVN. Experience show that even after years of using TortoiseSVN, users will still routinely corrupt working copies by doing one of the above. Once corrupted, it is typically infeasible to repair the working copy.

Fortunately SVN 1.7 (not yet released) will eliminate alot of this crap by centralizing metadata in one big .svn folder at the root of the working copy, like git and mercurial.

> and errors about SVN .tmp files/folders not existing

You might be using xcopy to manipulate working copies.
When you use xcopy to copy a folder then it will omit empty folders (unless you use the `/E` switch).

This will cause the `.svn/tmp` folders in your working copy to be omitted, effectively corrupting your working copy.

Comment: No, I leterally right click a sub-dir and use the TortoiseSVN shell-extension "rename" option. All works, until I try to commit the parent dir, as per Tortoise instructions

Comment: @John: your working copy might already have been corrupted before the rename.

Comment: When _IS_ SVN 1.7 coming out?

Comment: @John: It's planned for December 2010. But don't hold your breath; the planned release date has already been moved a couple of times.

Comment: I have exaclty the same problem. The rename works, but when I commit I get a merge conflict without fail. EVERY TIME.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think renaming is not a good idea when working with SVN, just because it's so easy to make a mess of it.  It can get especially ugly if you have a group of developers working of the same codebase and you make use of branches.

If you are not too concerned with the change history I suggest manually making a copy of the folder (i.e. via Explorer not SVN), renaming it (again via Explorer), delete all the .svn folders inside it (so you have a clean unversioned folder), and then SVN add it (and the files inside) to the repo.  Then just SVN-delete the old folder.  Of course this doesn't solve the problem if someone else was editing the same source files or was using a branch, but at least it forces you to think about the implications of a rename.

Comment: *If you are not too concerned with the change history* :)

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is set up well, you shouldn't have these kinds of issues.  But having lots of temporary files and folders as you say you do can cause this kind of problem.

Renaming directly in the repository will probably solve most of your problems, but could still cause some difficult merge conflicts if your temporary files have been modified before the rename.

If you can, try to put any temporary files and folders into a parent folder that you can add to svn:ignore and you will get rid of a lot of these problems.

Comment: It's the SVN hidden files which it's complaining about I think, not my own temp files.

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting and your folder structure?

Comment: The described errors indicate working copy corruption at the client side. How the repository is set up is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rename a folder/file if you have more than one active branch. SVN does not keep the necessary meta data to deal with it - so you will get a merge conflict.  Neither does GIT. Bazaar highlights renaming as one reason to switch to their system.

Comment: The question is like 7 years old. Renaming folders in 2017 mostly works as expected. The only caveat is the one you mention (porting changes between branches does not recognise renamed folders as the same object) though there're workarounds. I particularly use the "Repair move" feature in TortoiseSVN before I commit the merge where the rename happens.

Comment: I am using SVN 1.8.5. Repair move will still result in a merge conflict if there are changes to files in one branch that have been renamed in the other. A simple experiment on virgin repositories in both SVN and GIT will show this. Again, this is is something Bazaar explicitly addresses.